# Writing ICS Android apps which are backwards compatible

Tags: android, calendar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm writing an app that adds calendar events.

For OS versions prior to ICS, I need to use contentResolver queries which are unsupported and subject to change.

With ICS the API to do this sort of thing is to use the CalendarContract provider. So I plan to detect the OS API version and use the appropriate methods for pre ICS OS and ICS.

In my manifest I have the following to support Android 2.1 to 4.x:

```
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="14"
```

But the CalendarContract isn't available to import unless I set the `minSdkVersion` to 14, which makes the app inaccessible to anyone running anything prior to ICS.

How do I support older versions of the OS while adding support for new OS features on phones with ICS?

Do I create two versions of the app and upload both to the marketplace? Will users see the appropriate version for their OS?

Comment: There is an implementation of this functionality available in the SMS Backup Plus application for android which is open source and available on github. This is my fork with the respective functionality added, you can also look at the main project for a similar implementation. https://github.com/QuintinRobinson/sms-backup-plus/blob/4f321d547e1db4c62000d7db81525ac668df8c97/src/com/zegoggles/smssync/CalendarHelper.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you can do to make this work:

Have the minSDK version set to 2.1 and the target version to ICS.

Then, In properties of your project, build against ICS (android 4.0)..

This way, you are building against 4.0, which will include the functionality you need in ICS, yet you will still support android 2.1

As long as you don't call any ICS APIs when it is running on 2.1 (you will get classnotfound exception if you do), you will be fine.